# Uber style info window on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to show Uber type info window that can be opened all time and that can be moved on camera view update and fit to the screen instead of cut or overlap issue.

**What I want :**

[image]

**What I have tried:**
`implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'`

**custom_marker_infowindow_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_marker_right"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_marker_right"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/markerSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/markerSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/destination_location" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/marker_car"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_timing_right"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:background="@drawable/marker_square_hours"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_address_right"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:background="@drawable/marker_square_address"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
IconGenerator iconFactory_right = new IconGenerator(mContext);
iconFactory_right.setBackground(null);

View view_right = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.custom_marker_infowindow_right, null);
iconFactory_right.setContentView(view_right);

LinearLayout ll_marker_right = (LinearLayout) view_right.findViewById(R.id.ll_marker_right);
int width_ll_right = ll_marker_right.getLayoutParams().width;
ll_marker_right.setPadding((width_ll_right / 2) - (iv_marker_right.getLayoutParams().width / 2), 0, 0, 0);

mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(destinationLocation).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory_right.makeIcon("current"))));
```

**What I get :**   
 
[image]

As we see, I am not getting full marker and marker is getting cut and in some cases it overlaps between two. I have also tried `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 450));` to add padding, but in every case it is not working properly.
So I would like to implement Uber type info window that can be moved on camera view update and fit to the screen.

**Any help will be highly appreciated..!! Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Is there any solution yet?